# How to add a custom column to MacOS Finder?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, exif, finder

I would love to show a custom column in MacOS Finder to display certain EXIF Tags from image files. Is there a way to extend the Finder?

Answer (score 0):

don't think so, maybe check on the Apple Script email list or Automator community. They will know how to query Finder to do it. Also it would be in the Finder's scriptable API dictionary and documentation if it's possible out of the box.